# Android in-app billing validation

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm using android in-app billing version 3 in my app, and I want to validate a transaction after purchase on server. Is there a way to check if transaction valid or not?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for comment, but I know that link, I know how to make purchase, but in-app-billing wasn't secure, so I want to validate transaction, to check if user really made a purchase or no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation is the same as the one on the device: you get some data and a signature, then you use your public key to validate the signature. If it verifies, you save the transaction info in a DB, etc. and send an `OK` response to the client (your Android app).

Answer (score 0):

Read this-

To start a purchase request, your application sends a getBuyIntent request, specifying the product ID of the item to purchase, along with other parameters. You should record the product ID when you create a new in-app product in the Developer Console.
Google Play returns a Bundle that contains a PendingIntent which you application uses to start the checkout UI for the purchase.
Your application launches the pending intent by calling the startIntentSenderForResult method.
**When the checkout flow finishes (that is, the user successfully purchases the item or cancels the purchase), Google Play sends a response Intent to your onActivityResult method. The result code of the onActivityResult has a result code that indicates whether the purchase was successful or canceled. The response Intent contains information about the purchased item, including a purchaseToken String that is generated by Google Play to uniquely identify this purchase transaction.** *(You can use this information)*

Once you know if the transaction has been completed successfully, you can update your server accordingly, if that's what you want.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but there are applications, like "freedom", which can hack your app, and user can do free purchases with a fake credit card .I just want to know is there a way(may be a url) to check  if transaction is real or fake.

Comment: If you would use Google in app billing functionality, you will not have to worry about these things. Fake credit card no way.

Comment: So in-app billing isn't so secure.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to validate. I think you should check the response codes listed in the [API reference](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html).